# Boost ASIO SSL get the number of available bytes for read

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio, tcpclient

From [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp), the size of the buffer available for reading is 1024 bytes. However, in the `boost::asio::buffer()` of `handle_write()`, I can't put that number. The program would give an error:

> Write failed: uninitialized

The program would only work if I put exactly the number of bytes sent from the server.

So I tried to use the function `available()` which I found defined in the include file `basic_socket.hpp` to tell the number of available bytes to read, but I'm not sure how to call this function. Please assist!

```
void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        size_t len = socket_.available();
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
                                boost::asio::buffer(reply_, len),
                                boost::bind(&SSLClient::handle_read, this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The question is: In this example, how can I read all the bytes available?

Comment: I am not really sure I understand your question but you simple need to read until you have received the amount of bytes that your protocol requires.

Comment: @inf  Yes I want to read everything available in the buffer. Notice that everything is asynchronous, so it's not under my control to loop or something. I have to asynchronously set boost to do this. How can I make my question clearer?

Comment: It's not in a loop but it's still under your control. If the callback is fired and you haven't yet received all the bytes you need you just call `async_read` (or whichever form thereof) again.

Comment: @inf That could work, except that if I don't know the number of bytes I'm receiving, it'll be like as many executions as the number of bytes, which is very inefficient! Right? Imagine the number of bytes to be received is a prime number. How can I resolve this efficiently without knowing the number of bytes to be received?

Comment: What kind of protocol are you using where you don't know the message size or any logical delimiter?

Comment: @inf It's my own protocol actually. I'm writing this from scratch.

Comment: Still, how do you define a message in your protocol?

Comment: @inf It's my own client/server pair . My plan is to send and receive messages. A single "write" command is a message. I'm planning also to send and receive files the same way. I chop the file into chunks and write using `async_write`.

Comment: Ok, then you have to realize at this point that this model does not work with TCP as the number of write calls on the one side does not have to match the number of read calls on the other side. Multiple writes could become one read or one write could become multiple reads. That's why you need some form of application layer protocol which then enables you to implement the read loop described above. Of course, you don't have to reinvent your own protocol but can use exisiting ones such as HTTP (line based) or Apache Thrift (binary).

Comment: @inf Do you know how to combine such protocols with boost asio ssl, the one I'm using right now? Could you please send me in the right direction?

Comment: For the two mentioned above you are probably better off using existing libraries. If you want to get your hands dirty and use boost asio tcp/ssl I would say to implement a simple binary protocol. Something like a simple header consisting of the message size and message type followed by the payload. Like that you will get a feeling for how all that works internally and also learn about caveats such as endianess or integer serialization.

Comment: @inf Thanks. I'll try implementing a protocol myself which starts with the size of the message so that I know when to stop. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @inf Can I ask, please? What does the error "Unintialized" mean?

Comment: I can just guess, but maybe the buffer does have size zero or you are using a socket that you didn't proper initialize.

Comment: @inf That's somewhat impossible... because the only thing triggering this error is the number of bytes I choose to read (as I mention in the question). If the number of bytes is larger than the number available to read, this error occurs.